# How can I reference libraries in another project within Eclipse Helios?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, libraries

We have a problem at the place that I work with referencing multiple projects in our code.  Basically, we have a product, which I'll call Leviathan.  This project has quite a number of other versions, each of which we maintain as separate projects in Eclipse.  As developers, we typically have multiple projects (multiple versions) open in Eclipse simultaneously, as we get helpline calls about older versions (as well as developing simultaneously multiple versions).

We also have test code, which is in a different project for each distribution of Leviathan.  I name my projects `Leviathan_<branch name>`.  So, for example, in my Eclipse workspace, I might have projects like:

```
Leviathan_scott\ (my branch)
Leviathan_9.2\
Leviathan_9.3\
Leviathan_10.0\
Leviathan_10.1\
Test_scott\
Test_10.0
```

My branch is a copy of our trunk, so we can consider that the most active development line.

The problem is that we reference some libraries in Leviathan\lib  in our test code.  Each developer may name their projects slightly differently.  So, in developing the test project's .classpath, we reference the project Leviathan\ (no additions).  The classpath for this project (which is checked into our source control system) might look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry excluding="**/*.MySCMServerInfo" kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/abbot-1.0.2/abbot.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/abbot-1.0.2/costello.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/dbunit-2.4.8/dbunit-2.4.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/easymock-3.0/easymock-3.0.jar" sourcepath="lib/easymock-3.0/easymock-3.0-sources.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="jar:platform:/resource/Test/lib/easymock-3.0/easymock-3.0-javadoc.jar!/"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/objenesis-1.2/objenesis-1.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/privilegedAccessor-1.0.2/privilegedAccessor_1.0.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/unitils-3.1/unitils-core/unitils-core-3.1.jar" sourcepath="lib/unitils-3.1/unitils-core/src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/unitils-3.1/unitils-database/unitils-database-3.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/unitils-3.1/unitils-dbmaintainer/unitils-dbmaintainer-3.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/unitils-3.1/unitils-dbunit/unitils-dbunit-3.1.jar" sourcepath="lib/unitils-3.1/unitils-dbunit/src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/unitils-3.1/unitils-inject/unitils-inject-3.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/unitils-3.1/unitils-mock/unitils-mock-3.1.jar" sourcepath="lib/unitils-3.1/unitils-mock/src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/unitils-3.1/unitils-orm/unitils-orm-3.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/unitils-3.1/unitils-spring/unitils-spring-3.1.jar" sourcepath="lib/unitils-3.1/unitils-spring/src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/unitils-3.1/unitils-testng/unitils-testng-3.1.jar" sourcepath="lib/unitils-3.1/unitils-testng/src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="data"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/unitils-3.1/unitils-core/lib/ognl-2.6.9.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/testng-5.14.1/testng-5.14.1.jar" sourcepath="lib/testng-5.14.1/testng-5.14.1-src.zip"/>
    <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/Leviathan"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Leviathan/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Leviathan/lib/hibernate3.jar" sourcepath="/Leviathan/lib/src/hibernate-3.6.0-src.zip"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="classes"/>
</classpath>
```

When a developer loads the Test project into his/her individual Eclipse workspace, he/she would need to link the project to the original Leviathan project by going to Preference->Java Build Path->Projects and add the Leviathan_scott project.

The thing is, this of course doesn't change any of the `<classpathentry ... >` entries that refer to "Leviathan\lib".  So, we have to do one of two things:

1. Change all of the references from `Leviathan` to `Leviathan_<branch name>` in my .classpath using a text editor find/replace.
2. Remove all of the references to Leviathan*.jar in Java Build Path and re-add the jars in Leviathan_scott*.jar.

The problem with these is that it needs to be done *every time* the .classpath is changed, which makes both of these seem less than ideal.  Our classpath isn't changed super-regularly, but I would say it's changed once or twice every two weeks.  I'd like to be able to link my project and have to perform only a single step in order to link these projects.

It seems like we could set up an environment variable within Eclipse and add this into the .classpath entries.  But, now we have a problem because if we have multiple Test projects in our workspace that we want to compile, this won't work.  Both of the test projects' .classpath entries will refer to the same environment variable, which of course can only point to one super project location.

It seems like I should be able to do this, but I don't know exactly how to accomplish it in Eclipse.  Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

~Scott

Comment: Apache Maven sorts out these kind of problems like a charm.

Comment: Agreed, but it's difficult to get 20 developers to switch to a new build system... If we *absolutely* have to, I might be able to make the case for it, but if it's possible to do without this, then I'd like to accomplish it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Eclipse's 'Classpath Variables'.

```
Window->Preferences->Java->Build Path->Classpath Variables
```

Define one or more variables like "Leviathan_under_test" and point it to the version you want to test.  Then, in the project build path, change the library reference to include the variable.

When you change the version of Leviathan you want to test, you change the variable and go.  If you have to, you can even have multiple variables for versions that are tested more often, i.e. "LEVIATHAN_LATEST", OR "LEVIATHAN_PROBLEM_CHILD", etc.

Comment: Well, this is what I meant when I talked about environment variables.  So, the problem here is that I still need to change the build path - if, for example, I wanted to download Test_10.0 and Test_scott, and have them compile in the same workspace, I'd need to change the variable in the .classpath file in at least one of the two Test projects.  Ideally, we'd like to avoid this, because it's not really any better than what we have at the moment - having to change Leviathan to Leviathan_scott or something similar.

Comment: Actually, once the variable is in the .classpath file, you don't change it; at least in the case of $LEVIATHAN for example.  The build works with the classpath variable value you've set in your workspace.  You can point it to a different target without having to edit files in your project.

Comment: Well, not quite.  How would I solve the problem where I have Leviathan_10.0, Leviathan_Test_10, Leviathan_scott, and Leviathan_test_scott in my workspace, all open at the same time, and I want Leviathan_test_scott to point to Leviathan_scott and Leviathan_test_10 to point to Leviathan_10.0?

Comment: The theoretical answer would be to use multple workspaces because each one can have its own values for the environment variables.  If you want to have all those versions of the projects loaded into one workspace, you will have to create multiple variables, with explicit names, "LEVIATHAN_TEST_SCOTT" & "LEVIATHAN_10.0" for use by each project.  In reality, that isn't too much different from maintaining the classpath of each project directly.  You have an advanced build config problem(challenge) so you need to look at more robust build tools. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration

Answer (score 2):

This is a dependency management issue and there's lots of de-facto standard tools to help!  I strongly suggest you utilise [ANT](http://ant.apache.org/) with [Ivy's](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) dependency Managment or use [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) (or any otehr build tool that has dependency management).

With either of those I'd use a artifact repository maanger such as [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/) or Artifactory as well, so you have the one true source for your internally built artifacts.

This way you'll alway have the canonical version of the library that you want, when you want it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use external tools to manage the various project dependencies you could try to go to the single Leviathan projects Build path property, in the tab Order and Export, and check the libraries you need to run your tests.
in this way you don't need to import the libraries in the test project and by switching the project under test you automatically update the libraries

Comment: Hm... this looks promising.  So, you're saying instead of importing all of the libraries separately within a test project, export them from within the original leviathan project, then all I have to do is import the leviathan project into the test project?